# Is quality China manufacturing possible without being there?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, manufacturing

I'm looking for some help with manufacturing in China with respect to PCB fabrication and assembly, plastic injection molding and metal forging/brushing.
Common wisdom in our days is that one HAS to be in China otherwise you WILL get screwed.
But then there is an option of hiring an independent inspection company to do initial factory audit, to check parts before shipping them, etc.

Is [this](http://intouch-quality.com/services/#.U7hwnfldWSo) inspection company any good?

Is there a list of reliable PCB, plastic/metal production factories in China?
Is there a list of trusted inspection companies?

The main question is: is it possible to manufacture something of good quality in China without personally being there all the time or at all?

Comment: Let me ask you, how much experience with mfg have you got yourself to date (in the USA or elsewhere)?  What quantities will you be producing?

Comment: Of course it is 'possible'. Getting 'screwed' is possible too, as is bad quality, fading quality over time, etc. Inspection houses are not a panacea, for sure.

Comment: Nick, some small batch experience, but no large scale experience, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. Looking for 10K+. Spehro, what is a panacea in your view?

Comment: If, the extra profit you make by manufacturing in China more than justifies the cost of appointing someone to camp out there then it becomes a question about economics rather than EE.

Comment: I think, this question might lend itself better to chat.  So, I’ve created a chat room for it:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15551/mfg-in-china  @Jim , you don’t have enough reputation for general chat access, but you have write access in that particular room.

Comment: Andy, you're making a very valid point, thank you. So the next question is what is the best way to find such a person(s)? Is this a good idea to use inspection company as an "independent contractor" for this purpose as they might have materials/pcb/injection molding specialists? Has anyone heard of services like these in China?

Comment: @Jim- If you have high quantities, people, your people, on the ground. Relationships and big money are powerful motivators, so relatives are good. If you hire people they may end up taking money or favors from the folks they're supposed to be watching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is quality China manufacturing possible without being there?

If you are buying an already manufactured product then you can obtain samples and set in place whatever form of contractual arrangement seems likely to you to ensure that you get consistency of product. If you can specify the characteristics of a sample that have to be met tightly enough then failure to meet the requirement can be quantified, and this may well be enough of a protection.

If a product is being partially or fully customised to your order then you may want to know things are as they should be long before the 1,000 items finally arrive.

In my opinion, for a product that is being made specifically for you, if you want certainty over time then you or a person who is utterly 'your man*' has to be involved.

I tell people that I have two rules re manufacturing in China

- (1.)  ... **My number 1 rule for manufacturing in China is**

  - **"You have to be there"**
- (0.) My number 0 rule is -

  - **"Don't!"**

"0." is partially in jest  - but also partially not.

"**You have to be there**" means, if a product is being made for you to your specification then it is "very very very ... advisable" that a person who can competently assess the merits of what they see, and who you can trust to wholly represent only your interests, is present and has complete freedom of access at every major stage of manufacturing that is capable of "going wrong" OR  are able to freely inspect results as desired and have the power of veto if product does not meet specification. This could be done solely at final signoff provided that the product is able to be properly assessed at this point as having been manufactured "to specification" and provided that they are able to reject some or all of a batch at no cost to you if specification is not met and provided that this requirement is understood and agreed to by the manufacturer.

"**Don't**" really means that if you are not prepared to follow rule 1. do not start at all. Note that rule 1. does NOT mean that you have to be in China yourself or have someone who is a member of your company on site.

My personal hard-won experience has been that in the large majority of cases, even when I felt I had a good relationship with people, was well understood and had clearly spelled out what was required, as soon as I left a mysterious change came about in the manner in which requirements were met. Attempts to remedy this from afar in a number of entirely different situations met with minimal success. I do have some contacts who I am confident will do as asked and whose judgement I can trust - but it is not the norm. Others may experience things differently, but enough will recount similar enough experiences to mine.

I have heard various horror stories re inspection companies - including incompetence, high cost and colluding with manufacturers.

I know of at least one inspection company from personal experience that I would happily recommend. A client had them recommended by a contractor who used them extensively and what I saw of their work for my client confirmed the recommendation.  [If anyone wants company name and contact details ask me offlist -  all care no responsibility (see my profile page for email address.)] [FWIW - the team are mainly Chinese nationals and the owner? / manager is Indonesian. ]

There are sure to be other good ones, but at least some of the horror stories are sure to be true. China is an immense country. Even if only a small % of people fall in a given category you can be sure that there are  still a vast number of small entrepreneurs, manufacturers, resellers, confidence men and outright thieves. Telling them apart can be hard. There are many more resellers of most products than there are manufacturers. However, it is common practice for resellers to represent themselves as manufacturers, and the reality behind photos of machine shops, large offices and impressive premise MAY be instead a small room on an upper floor of a Shenzhen outer suburbs high rise.

---

**Contracts:**

The following is "2nd hand" based on comments made to me my Chinese associates.
Contracts:  I have been told by a number of Chinese companies that a way of ensuring compliance with requirements is to have a "contract". This means more in the Chinese context than it may in western circles  -  a contract in the west may be a basis for subsequent successful litigation but in China it seems it may have special magic. In the past contracts were enforced by 'the party' but they have now become the preserve of the legal system.
I was advised by one manufacturer (one I'd trust without a contract :-) ) that contracts are considered by many to be outdated but he considered them to still have considerable value.
However, (see below) there is growing western opinion that the new legal system enforced contracts have considerable value.

[China law blog - 3 rules - worth a read](http://www.chinalawblog.com/2013/04/the-three-rules-for-your-china-contract.html)

[Canadian trade commission advice](http://www.tradecommissioner.gc.ca/eng/document.jsp?did=132281)

[Wikipedia - Contract law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labour_Contract_Law_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China)

[Chinese contract laws](http://www.npc.gov.cn/englishnpc/Law/2007-12/11/content_1383564.htm)

[And again ...](http://www.china.org.cn/china/LegislationsForm2001-2010/2011-02/12/content_21908031.htm)

[And again ...](http://www.novexcn.com/contract_law_99.html)

Comment: Hi, Russell, looking forward to hearing more from you on the topic(s), I'm sure a lot of people will find it useful. China is changing rapidly and we need to hear the latest info from people that are plugged in like yourself. I've found this guy to be quite interesting: http://qualityinspection.org/

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment - NOT part of my answer per se: *In terms of competence the person could obviously be a woman. Chinese culture is complex in attitudes to women and I have still not (after only 15 visits :- ) got any certainty of how a woman in this sort of role would affect results. On the one hand, women are involved at all levels of business and industry and are often involved in major management positions. In the Chinese workplace as a whole you are much more likely to find women filling roles typically seen as male oriented in "the West". ...

Comment: However, I have also  experienced situations where male dominance is very visible.  
I suspect that socially your interests could be equally well represented by a woman as by a man but cannot be certain. The sole electrical engineer at the 1st factory in China that I was involved with was a woman. The project manager, a member of company upper management and lead designer for the plastic moulded products at the second was a woman.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.  And as in any good manufacturing scheme, having good documentation and incoming inspection and quality standards set and clearly documented will make your life easy.

Expecting someone from around the world to read your mind doesn't work.

Of course there is bad people and incompetent people everywhere.

There is only one certainty with China, is that they are changing and very fast.  Stories from someone about having been screwed over even just 3 years ago really is irrelevant.

Even IP rules and patents is changing rapidly and will eventually be as strong as they are in the rest of the world.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, can you recommend some relevant reading materials?